# How to print string value out of while loop?

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi I am trying to fetch value from database and print that all value on console. when I print value inside the while loop its work and give all value as a string but when I try to print all value out of while loop it gives me only last value how can I get all value out of loop as a string

Here is my code

```
import java.sql.*;
public class commoditywise {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s=null;
        String id = "paddy";
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName = "mandi";
        String userId = "root";
        String password = "";
        String market=null;
        String rate=null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try{ 
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId, password);
            statement=connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "select ch.mandihindi,cw.price from commoditywise cw inner join mandihindi ch on ch.mandieng=cw.mandi where cw.commodity=  '"+id+"'";

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while(resultSet.next()){
                market=resultSet.getString("mandihindi");
                rate=resultSet.getString("price");

                market=market.concat("~");
                rate=rate.concat("|");

                s=market.concat(rate);
                s=s.replaceAll(" ", "");
            }
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get my desired out put?

Comment: @LifeRunsOnCode  thanks for edit can u could u please help me

Comment: Flagged : Unclear what you are asking, problem can be solved with some very very basic research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Hope this is what you want to get!!!

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Commoditywise {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = null;
        String id = "paddy";
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName = "mandi";
        String userId = "root";
        String password = "";
        String market = null;
        String rate = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + dbName,
                    userId, password);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "select ch.mandihindi,cw.price from Commoditywise cw inner join mandihindi ch on ch.mandieng=cw.mandi where cw.commodity=  '"
                    + id + "'";

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                market = resultSet.getString("mandihindi");
                rate = resultSet.getString("price");
                s += market.concat("~").concat(rate).concat("|");
            }
            s = s.replaceAll(" ", "").substring(0, s.length() - 1);
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Suggestion : [improve your code convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-135089.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can put each value into an array as you read them and then print from the array.

Comment: can u give me some small code